# Compare two different folders with an exclusion set

Tags: powershell

I have the below script which compares two different folders on my desktop

```
$count1 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\users\mhopkins\desktop\test\Application' -Recurse -Force
$count2 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\users\mhopkins\desktop\test\R611' -Recurse -Force
$results = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $count1 -DifferenceObject $count2
```

Both `fileX.txt` and `fileY.txt` exist in `\Application\` but not `\R611\`. How can I make it so that only `fileY.txt` is returned? Aka, adding an "allowed differences" dataset?

Comment: So what is in Folder R611?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PowerShell 3 this is relatively trivial:

```
$allowedDiffs = "FileX.txt","FileZ.txt"
Compare-Object (gci 'c:\users\mhopkins\desktop\test\Application' -recurse -force') ('c:\users\mhopkins\desktop\test\R611' -recurse -force) | Where-Object {$_.InputObject -notin $allowedDiffs}
```

Otherwise, in PowerShell 2, you would pipe The result of the compare-object command to a foreach loop, and then perform another for-each loop on the $allowedDiffs array.